# Spring Boot - HTTPS on localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created an application in Spring Boot and enabled SSL in application.properties using below config

```
server.port=8085
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.ssl.key-alias=selfsigned
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-password=password
```

I have also created self signed certificate **keystore.jks** for accessing via localhost.

below is the result of `keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks -v`

```
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: selfsigned
Creation date: 5-okt-2018
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=localhost, OU=UniteInboxAPI, OU=DEV, OU=PKI, OU=Services, O=ING, L=Holualoa, ST=HI, C=US
Issuer: CN=localhost, OU=UniteInboxAPI, OU=DEV, OU=PKI, OU=Services, O=ING, L=Holualoa, ST=HI, C=US
Serial number: 68547095
Valid from: Fri Oct 05 17:24:46 CEST 2018 until: Sat Oct 05 17:24:46 CEST 2019
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  E5:48:B0:2F:DA:5C:BE:8E:30:A9:A6:CF:B3:07:55:DC
         SHA1: EC:C2:B2:F5:70:CA:57:47:8F:54:A7:5E:54:C2:A1:29:51:2F:51:62
         SHA256: 7F:EA:88:65:24:A7:39:20:93:14:54:0D:53:B7:50:85:D9:8B:55:5F:72:43:EB:94:99:FC:93:CE:25:4A:BA:27
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
```

When I try to access it via Chrome/Mozilla, the host is not reachable and my endpoints are not served.

Kindly assist if I need to do any additional configuration/ have to import any certificates in browser.

Regards,
Suvojit

Comment: In all my years I've never needed to run SSL locally, are you sure this is something you really need? A common mode of deployment is that your non-HTTPS application is running in a cluster of its peers behind a load balancer, which is often where SSL termination takes place. I understand there could be myriad other modes of deployment, and I've certainly seen and done some of those, just never had the need to mess with HTTPS locally...

Comment: Yes thats needed to test the certificates and for Mutual Authentication for the purpose of implementation :)

Comment: (1) yes for browser (or any decent client) to trust a selfsigned cert you need to add that cert to its truststore. use `keytool -export -keystore whatever [-alias whatever] [-rfc] -file outfile` to get the cert in a file. Firefox uses its own store and you must add from its Options/Advanced/Certificates tab. Chrome uses the platform's store and can be accessed from settings+Advanced/Manage certificates or directly. Both of these should handle either DER or PEM (-rfc) format, although the latter is more convenient if _you_ want to look at or use the file later. ...

Comment: ... (2) however, that should give an error about 'not trusted' or 'not private' -- NOT 'not reachable', which suggest you have some other mistake or problem as well. But without details it is effectively impossible to help. What exactly are the error messages? Have you tried non-browser clients like `curl` or `wget` or even `openssl s_client`, and what errors if any do you get? (openssl s_client _will_ accept a selfsigned or otherwise untrustworthy cert.)

Comment: I receive this as error in Mozilla (SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_ALERT) and in chrome it gives me 401 Unauthorized error. Is there any way to disable SSL for my localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your RestTemplate like that:

1. Add dependency:

   ```
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
   ```
2. Provide RestTemplate bean:

```java
@Bean
private RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        SSLContext sslContext = buildSslContext();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }

private SSLContext buildSslContext() {
        try {
            char[] keyStorePassword = sslProperties.getKeyStorePassword();
            return new SSLContextBuilder()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(
                            KeyStore.getInstance(new File(sslProperties.getKeyStore()), keyStorePassword),
                            keyStorePassword
                    ).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to instantiate SSL context", ex);
        } finally {
            sslProperties.setKeyStorePassword(null);
            sslProperties.setTrustStorePassword(null);
        }
    }
```

3. Provide required SSL properties in your application.properties or application.yaml file:

```
server:
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store: /path/to/key.keystore
        key-store-password: password
        key-alias: alias
        trust-store: /path/to/truststore
        trust-store-password: password
```

That's it. Now you can see your Tomcat is starting on 8080 (or another port) (https).

Alternatively, you can use [my spring boot starter](https://github.com/EugeneLesnov/spring-boot-starter-rest)